# Question on the reflection principle of a brownian motion proof

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

**Preliminaries** : *My question follow the proof of the Reflection principle that you can consult [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)) (I do not copy/paste for the sake of the global understanding of my question). Every notations are taken from the wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)), **except** this one $X(t)$ that I type $X_t$.*

---

I want to show :
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\tau_a \leq t, X_{t-\tau_a} < 0\right) \overset{?}= \mathbb{P}\left(\tau_a \leq t, X_{t-\tau_a} > 0\right) \ \ \ (*)
$$

I do not understand why my brief proof could not work ? I detail.

**My proof :**
For proving that I have simply said : $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a brownian motion so it is equal by law to $(-X_t)_{t\geq 0}$. Moreover $\tau_a$ and $X$ are independant so : $\mathbb P_{(\tau_a,X)}=\mathbb P_{(\tau_a,-X)}$

---

***Versus***

---

**Common proof :** 
Every proofs I have seen about, prove (*) like that :

Knowing that $X$ and $\tau_a$ are independant, it exists $F:\mathbb R_+\times C^0(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$, bounded, borelian :
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\tau_a \leq t, X(t-\tau_a) < 0\right) &= \mathbb E \left(F(\tau_a,X)\right)\\
&=\phi(\tau_a)
\end{align}

such that :
$$
\forall s\in\mathbb R_+,\ \phi(s)=\mathbb P(s\leq t, X_{t-s}<0)
$$

Since $-X$ is a brownian motion we can conclude :
$$
\forall s\in\mathbb R_+,\ \phi(s)=\mathbb P(s\leq t, X_{t-s}>0)
$$
That achieve the common proof.

---

**Question:**

- I understand the *common proof* but my question is why we cannot do, as simply as it is, *mine* ?
- Why we do the common proof rather than my basic idea ?
- Does my brief and basic idea work actually ?
- Is it something flawed, missed in my basic proof ?

Comment: The random variables $\tau_a$ and $X_{t-\tau_a}=W(t)-a$ seem quite non independent. Foe example, $P(\tau_a>t,W(t)-a>0)=0\ne P(\tau_a>t)P(W(t)-a>0)$.

Comment: I have read your example and it is a good one. Nevertheless $\tau_a$ and $X_t$ (for $t\geq 0$) are not independant because $X_t$ (for $t\geq 0$) is independant of $\mathcal F_{\tau_a}$ ?

Comment: Yes, the process $(X_t)$ and the random variable $\tau_a$ are independent. Is this your question?

Comment: So just I do not understand : why does your first comment show that my proof is wrong ?

Comment: Because your proof is based on the conception that $\tau_a$ and $X_{t-\tau_a}$ would be independent, is it not?